# Polynomial Factorisation - Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Im attempting a linear algebra question in which I have been given the following quadratic form $q(x,y,z) = x^2+25y^2+10xy+2yz$. I have to find a basis $B$ such that $[f]_B$ has the real canonical form, where $f$ is the corresponding symmetric bilinear form. I know that the first step is to factor the polynomial into a sum of squares, however I end up with $q(x,y,z)=(x+5y)^2+2yz$. I've tried writing $2yz$ as $(y+z)^2$ and then proceeding from there, but I just keep going round in circles. Can anyone show me the correct way to factor this so that I can proceed with the question? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quadratic form $q(x, y, z)$ is not a sum of squares, at least, not over $\Bbb R$. But like all symmetric bilinear forms, it can be written as a sum and difference of squares.

**Hint** $$4 y z = (y + z)^2 - (y - z)^2.$$

Comment: So would I write $2yz = (\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}})^2 - (\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}})^2$?

Comment: @Arron Yes, that certain gives you a sum-and-difference of squares.

Comment: Thank You so much for your help!

Comment: @Arron You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful!